# How to assign List<dynamic> to List<Khana>, where Khana is a model class in a parameter in Flutter-Firestore?

Tags: flutter, firebase-realtime-database, flutter-web

Actually, I am trying to get data from firebase and I am suffering from the Error:

> Expected a value of type List < Khana >, but got one of type 'List< dynamic >'

I am getting data from the firebase, my fetchData function is:

```
Future<void> fetchAndSetOrder() async {
    try {
      await collectionRef.get().then((querySnapshot) {
        for (var result in querySnapshot.docs) {
          debugPrint("${result.runtimeType}=> ${result.data()}");
          Orders newOrder = Orders.fromFirestore(result);
          debugPrint("\n new order : $newOrder");
          // _Order.add(newOrder);
          debugPrint("new order added");
          // _Order.add(Orders.fromMap(result as Map));
        }
      });
    } catch (e) {
      debugPrint("Error during Fetch:- $e");
    }
  }
```

and the Orders.fromFirestore constructor is:

```
factory Orders.fromFirestore(DocumentSnapshot<Object?> snapshot) {
    final data = snapshot.data() as LinkedHashMap<String, dynamic>;
    debugPrint("Inside From Firestore Function");
    return Orders(
      khana: data['khana'], // here is the error...
      orderNumber: data['orderNumber'],
      userId: data['userId'],
      paymentCash: data['paymentCash'],
      dateTime: data['dateTime'],
    );
  }
```

Orders class has:

```
class Orders{
  List<Khana> khana;  // this is another ModelClass
  String userId;
  int orderNumber;
  DateTime dateTime;
  bool paymentCash;
  Orders({
    required this.khana,
    required this.userId,
    required this.orderNumber,
    required this.dateTime,
    required this.paymentCash,
  });
}
```

so, the issue is how can I read List from the firestore as a List ? Any other possible way to solve this issue.
My Khana Model is:

```
import 'dart:convert';

class Khana {
  String mealName;
  int id;
  int price;
  int quantity;
  Khana({
    required this.mealName,
    required this.price,
    required this.quantity,
    required this.id,
  });

  Map<String, dynamic> toMap() {
    final result = <String, dynamic>{};

    result.addAll({'mealName': mealName});
    result.addAll({'id': id});
    result.addAll({'price': price});
    result.addAll({'quantity': quantity});

    return result;
  }

  factory Khana.fromMap(Map<String, dynamic> map) {
    return Khana(
      mealName: map['mealName'] ?? '',
      id: map['id']?.toInt() ?? 0,
      price: map['price']?.toInt() ?? 0,
      quantity: map['quantity']?.toInt() ?? 0,
    );
  }

  String toJson() => json.encode(toMap());

  factory Khana.fromJson(String source) => Khana.fromMap(json.decode(source));
}
```

I am trying to read a List from the firestore snapshot.data(), it says it's return data type is List, and I want this list to be assigned to the List of my own ModelClass (i.e Khana), and I am not able to do that.
I even tried

```
factory Orders.fromFirestore(DocumentSnapshot<Object?> snapshot) {
    final data = snapshot.data() as LinkedHashMap<String, dynamic>;
    debugPrint("Inside From Firestore Function");
    return Orders(
      khana: data['khana'] as List<Khana>, 
      orderNumber: data['orderNumber'],
      userId: data['userId'],
      paymentCash: data['paymentCash'],
      dateTime: data['dateTime'],
    );
  }
```

but got the same issue :(

Comment: Where are you getting error

Comment: when I am returning
Orders(
      khana: data['khana'],    // here is the error...
      orderNumber: data['orderNumber'],
      userId: data['userId'],
      paymentCash: data['paymentCash'],
      dateTime: data['dateTime'],
    );
in the factory Orders.fromFireStore(...) function

Comment: Your error refers to `MyModelClass` could you produce the code of `MyModelClass`

Comment: And I dont think the above mentioned line is producing the said error

Comment: by, MyModelClass, I meant Khana which is my model class, lemme edit to remove the confusion

Comment: The problem is You can't directly do `as List<Khana>` You'll have to make FromJson specifically to Khana Class and then use it as `data['khana'].fromJson()).toList()`

Comment: ok, I got another error:
`Error during Fetch:- NoSuchMethodError: 'fromJson'
method not found
Receiver: Instance of 'List<dynamic>'
Arguments: []`

Comment: In data['khana'], data is a snapshot.data() from the firebase btw

Comment: Yes that should be properly casted, `as List<Khana>` won't work

Comment: Produce Khana Model, I'll try to help you out

Comment: I have added Khana Model in the question :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your khana to this

```
khana: List<Khana>.from(data['khana'].map((x)=>Khana.fromJson(x)));
```

Comment: Thankyou, it worked, but prompted this error:
 FormatException: SyntaxError: Unexpected token 'b', "burger" is not valid JSON
Can you explain, whats the reason for this error?

Comment: You are using json encoding.i don't know why , replace your khana.fromjson to khana.frommap() hope it will solves the error